# Real time application using ReactJS+ChartJS+SSE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to build reactjs application. In this application I want to use chartjs to show line chart by subscribing the Server sent events(SSE).

I want to update line chart when there is new message from SSE. For that I've developed below code but the chart is not updating when there is new message. I'm printing the new message values in console and I can see those messages. But my chart is not updating on real-time bases.

for e.g if there is new message from SSE, the chart needs to be updated.

when I minimize my browser and maximize by browser that chart is updating with pulled messages values.
Once client connect to my server where SSE emit.

Please find screenshots here [image: Screenshot1] [image: Screenshot2]

Here is the code

```
let xAxis =[];
let yAxis=[];
class LineChartComponent extends Component
{
   constructor(props) {     
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      data: []
     } 
     this.eventSource = new EventSource('http://mydomainname:8090/kafka-messages');    
   }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.eventSource.onmessage = (e) => this.updateChart(JSON.parse(e.data));   
  }

  updateChart(message){
    let trgTS =message.TrgTS;
    let value =parseFloat(100.0*message.Attributes[0].V/message.Attributes[1].V).toFixed(2);
      xAxis.push(trgTS);
      yAxis.push(value)
      console.log(trgTS,value); // I can see the new messages values in console 
      this.setState(Object.assign({}, {
        data: {
          labels:  xAxis,
          datasets:[
             {
                label:'cycle time',
                data: yAxis ,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "#3cba9f"
              }
          ]
        }
      }));      
  }
   render()
   {
      return(
         <div>
            <Line data = {this.state.data} options = {{ maintainAspectRatio: false }} />
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: I faced the same issue in angular6 app and i resolved it by manually updating the chart using update method of chart. Not sure how to do it in React but you can use something like this :  `this.chart.update();`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't have issue with Angular 6, even you don't need to update this.chart.update(). Automatically chart will refresh when there is new data in scope variable. I'm trying to find same solution with ReactJS.